# How to loop through a future list and serialize the results into _kEventSource

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to loop through dynamicEvents am getting errors: Functions must have an explicit list of parameters, the name 'dynamicEvents' is already defined. Also errors on missing identifier and expected to find')

```
Map<DateTime, List<Event>> _kEventSource = {};
Future<List<Welcome>> dynamicEvents =  fetchadvertannouncements();

    dynamicEvents.forEach((element) {
      _kEventSource[DateTime(  
        element.time.year,
        element.time.month,
        element.time.day,
      )] = _kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )] !=
              null
          ? [
              ..._kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )],
              element
            ]
          : [element];
  });
```

How do i go about this.The dynamic events are list from an API which i want to display on flutter table calender

Answer (score 0):

`dynamicEvents` is a Future, you can use it to handle the data when it arrives in the future or handle error. You need to use `await` or `then` to work with Future.

```
Map<DateTime, List<Event>> _kEventSource = {};
List<Welcome> dynamicEvents = await fetchadvertannouncements();

    dynamicEvents.forEach((element) {
      _kEventSource[DateTime(  
        element.time.year,
        element.time.month,
        element.time.day,
      )] = _kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )] !=
              null
          ? [
              ..._kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )],
              element
            ]
          : [element];
  });
```